Is is possible to specify dependencies in pyproject.toml without an install happening?
It might help to give the details of the specific problem I'm having:
Problem
Google's protobuf introduced a cross-version runtime guarantee. However, it did this in a clumsy manner that requires a from google.protobuf import runtime_version import, which only the very recent versions have available (>=5.27.0 as of this writing).
Therefore, if I have an earlier version of protobuf installed, like version 4.25.4, I get the following error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'runtime_version' from 'google.protobuf'

Moreover, I am using GCP (Google's cloud), and many of its tools have a stupifying matrix of limited protobuf versions that work for them, and which do not all match with each other. (Eg, BigTable, Apache Beam (Dataflow), and Composer.)
This means that it is very challenging to be able to create protocol buffers which can be used across the suite of GCP products that I am using for my data engineering and data pipeline needs.
Solution
The ideal solution would be Google not putting so many upper bounds on so many of their libraries, especially since some consider this a bad practice. But that solution is outside of my control.

So what I would like to do is to add dependencies to my protobuf message creation projects that introduce dependencies that are only needed by the runtimes that use the messages (either reading or writing them).
In other words, I want to ensure that the protobuf version used when I perform
protoc --python_out <out-dir> <my-proto-file.proto> -I <in-dir>

is less than or equal to the protobuf version used when using GCP's Dataflow, Composer, etc.
So, I would like something like the following on my protobuf message definition library:
pyproject.toml
[project]
name = "myprotobufmessage"
description = "The protobuf message I need to send, built for Python"
dependencies = [
    "protobuf",
]
***indirect-dependencies*** = [ # This is the crux of my question
    "apache-beam>=2.57.0",
    "google-cloud-logging>=3.8",
.
.
.

where indirect-dependencies is a key that does not exist.
This would act exactly like the dependencies key in regards to the dependency resolution mechanism, but it would not actually install anything and it would not create any locks or pins in the associated lock file.
(I use PDM, which very nicely creates a lock file that pins the exact versions used to build the library and provides hash sums of those versions. But I'm assuming that Poetry and other modern packaging tools have something similar.)
Is this possible? If not, is there any workaround where I can specify the actual dependence instead of the indirect dependence. In other words, I don't want to specify protobuf>=4.0,<5.0 because that's what Apache Beam requires. I want to specify apache-beam and let the resolver sort it out.
Currently, this is becoming a maddening headache because I cannot even remember where all of these indirect dependencies come from without putting in comments in the pyproject.toml file to explain where the dependency comes from. This is tough for me, but even worse when working as a group.
